# Pyspark got TypeError: can’t pickle _abc_data objects

Tags: python, pyspark

I’m trying to generate predictions from a pickled model with pyspark, I get the model with the following  command

`model = deserialize_python_object(filename)`

with `deserialize_python_object(filename)` defined as:

```
import pickle
def deserialize_python_object(filename):
try:
    with open(filename, ‘rb’) as f:
        obj = pickle.load(f)
except:
    obj = None
return obj
```

the error log looks like:

```
File “/Users/gmg/anaconda3/envs/env/lib**strong text**/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py”, line 189, in wrapper
    return self(*args)
  File “/Users/gmg/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py”, line 167, in __call__
    judf = self._judf
  File “/Users/gmg/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py”, line 151, in _judf
    self._judf_placeholder = self._create_judf()
  File “/Users/gmg/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py”, line 160, in _create_judf
    wrapped_func = _wrap_function(sc, self.func, self.returnType)
  File “/Users/gmg/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py”, line 35, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
  File “/Users/gmg/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py”, line 2420, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File “/Users/gmg/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py”, line 600, in dumps
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can’t pickle _abc_data objects
```

Comment: Asbtract base class can't be serialized/deserialized. This is true in pretty much every language, unless you include the implementation type in the serialization format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems that you are having the same problem like in this issue:
https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle/issues/180

What is happening is that pyspark's cloudpickle library is outdated for python 3.7, you should fix the problem with this crafted patch by now [until pyspark gets that module updated](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/26009).

Try using this workaround:

1. Install cloudpickle `pip install cloudpickle`
2. Add this to your code:

```
import cloudpickle
import pyspark.serializers
pyspark.serializers.cloudpickle = cloudpickle
```

monkeypatch credit https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle/issues/305